# Error accessing request.headers in Next.js middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, http-headers, middleware

I tried to access the `request.headers` in the **Next.js Middleware** but the data is not showing up.

If I access something else, the data can appear. If I display headers it gets an error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot delete property 'Symbol(set-cookie)' of #<HeadersList2>
```

[Code in Middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P158F.png):

```js
export function middleware(request) {
    console.log(request.credentials); // show -> same-origin
    console.log(request.method); // show -> GET

    console.log(request.headers); // page error
    console.log(request.headers.referer); // not show / undefined
}

export const config = {
    matcher: "/:path*/generate",
};
```

Fill in the data in the **request** variable:

[image]

Error when I display `request.headers`:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

You can't access the `headers` object directly inside the middleware. If you want to access a specific header you should use the `get` method.

```js
export function middleware(request) {
    console.log(request.headers.get('referer')); // Will output `referer` header value
    
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```